# What is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\cos\frac{k\pi}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

How to evaluate this:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor} \cos\frac{k\pi}{n}$$

where $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ denotes the largest integer not exceeding $\frac{n}{2}$

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Answer (score 1):

This is Riemann sum.
One Riemann sum for the integral of $x\mapsto \cos(\pi x)$ on $[0,\frac12]$ is
$$
\frac 1{\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor} \cos\frac{\pi k}{n}
$$
whose limit is
$$
\int_0^{1/2} \cos (\pi x) dx = \frac 1\pi \sin(\pi/2)
$$

Comment: I am not getting it .Please explain a bit more @Mookid.How to approach these problems in general

Comment: look carefully at the interval being described, and find the corresponding function. Here with $t_k = k/n, 0<k<n$ you describe $[0,1]$.